# Creating Same UI Supporting Different Screen Sizes?

Tags: java, android

I am Currently having designing problems in android studio.
I want to create UI which should looks same on every device but now i can't do that properly. i am using constraint layout and these are the screenshots :

For Android Screen Size 4.7 UI looks like below screenshot :

[image]

and For Android Screen 7.0 Size UI looks like this screenshot :

[image]

as the images shows the circular image on screen size 7 is pretty small and `edittext` is too looking worst.

How can i support both or more screen sizes while keeping the view like screen size 4.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **SDP - a scalable size unit** library for supporting different screens.

An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.
Here is the [LINK](https://github.com/intuit/sdp#sdp---a-scalable-size-unit)

Comment: Thank you Arbaz for giving your time. it looks good. Will be trying it first and then i'll let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adaptive constraints can be used to achieve this.

For example, instead of putting an image view of say 100 * 100 dp, you can use specify the width in percentage of the screen size.

ConstraintLayout comes with many tools to help you with such as barriers, percentageWidth, chains etc.

A nice blog to get you started on the same : https://proandroiddev.com/getting-your-constraints-right-constraintlayout-786254ed1166

(I am the author of the blog)

Answer (score 0):

To Support different screen sizes. Use ConstraintLayout. Google has solved the biggest problem for Android developers called Support different screen sizes by ConstraintLayout.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes