# GridLayout and CardView is not working perfectly with all devices

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, null

I have a complete Android project. I was made it by the `GridLayout` and `CardView`. Everything is well. I have tested this app with my all of the emulators, which are working fine, but while I'm trying to open my app with

> Lava Iris505

and

> Symphony Xplorer v60

it's not working perfectly. Please see this below image.
[image: Error]

But while I've installed this app on my Xioami Redmi 4x or any other Android Studio emulator, it's showing all my works like this below image.

[image: No Error]

My activity code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBG"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="736dp"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:padding="14dp"
                android:rowCount="3">

                <!-- Row 1 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/news24"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/news24" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/deshebideshe"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/deshebideshe" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <!-- Row 2 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/jamuna"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/jamuna" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/satv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/satv" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <!-- Row 2 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/jagobanglatv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/jagobanglatv" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/nrbtv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/nrbtv" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/rtvmusic"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/rtvmusic" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/qtv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/qtv" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/panvisiontv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/panvisiontv" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/millennium"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/millennium" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/btvworld"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/btvworld" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/probashibangla"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/probashibangla" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </GridLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

and my gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.gurujibd.ajkerkhobor"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "5.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.2.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: suggestion.. user `RecyclerView`.. :(

Comment: try changing the gridview height to wrapcontent. Dont hardcore the value of height and width. Use match parent or wrap content to support across all devices

Comment: while i'm changing the grideview height to match_parent or wrap_content it will showing blank activity. nothing is showing. how to solve? @NagendraHariKarthick

Comment: no one here to help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow**

I suggest you use **RecycleView** if you want to  archive that design which you posted.
also set **GridView** Layout manager to your **RecyclerView** For GridView [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587169/5995648)

And you are develop application which support  different screen size(mobile and tablet)
[click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51875376/5995648)

[image: design]

Happy Learning!!!