# How to make an Android App Support all Screen Sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have made an app using **Xamarin.Android** which has various views like, Textviews,Editexts,Spinners,Table layout etc. When i was making this app, i had just started android development so didn't pay as such of attention to Screen Sizes and only targeted the app for my personal mobile. Now i want my app to support from atleast 5 inch screen phones all the way to tablets. I read many solutions for Screen Sizes but can't decide which one is the most ideal to go forward with. What is the most ideal solution for my scenario?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476662/how-to-set-android-layout-to-support-all-screen-sizes

Comment: Read [Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51875376/5995648)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [**`supports-screens`**](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

If your application does not work well when resized to fit different screen sizes, you can use the attributes of the  element to control whether your application should be distributed to smaller screens or have its UI scaled up ("zoomed") to fit larger screens using the system's screen compatibility mode.

```
 <supports-screens
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

For more info read [**`Screen compatibility`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support)